# Lost email on Hotmail/Gmail after reinstalling iMac

Tags: macos, mac, email, microsoft-outlook, gmail

After I factory-restored (from the DVD)  my friend’s Snowleopard iMac she cannot access her email before that date from anywhere, including from a Win7 machine. She can log in and see every event after June 25 when I restored her iMac, sent mail, new mail etc - but all before that date is now gone.

Before that she was always able to read her past mail from any state she traveled, so the e-mails were not downloaded to her iMac and deleted from the servers…

She lives some 300 miles away from me, so I have no way accessing her iMac now, but if you have ever came across of this issue please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like she was downloading the emails using POP3 and removing the emails off the server.  If thats the case she might be able to recover the data file that stores the emails but unlikely given the description of the events.

Comment: @Ramhound I fear exactly the same, she was using OSX and Safari both I am very unfamiliar with, and after the fact there is no way to tell if Safari or the Mac was set to remove mail after opening them. What confuses me the most is if this was the case, how could she still read her e-mail from all over the US all these years. What burns me is that I need to make a trip this weekend if this is really all my doing by restoring her Mac to factory defaults, and try to fix it.